# Pythonic way to generate this list

Tags: python, list, coordinates

I'm looking for the fastest, and most 'pythonic' way to create the following list.

Say we have a coordinate grid represented as a list of tuples. When selecting any one of them we want to get a list of all the nearby coordinates as if they were inside a box centered on the coordinate we chose.

For example, if it's a 100x100 grid, and we choose (50,50), the list should start with (40,40) and end with (60,60), containing all the coords in between which would make a box.

I can do this using pygame collision detection, but the grid I'm working with is very large so the lookup cost become too high, and accessing the coordinates directly is a much better solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this?  Could you include some code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def lookup(x, y, l):
    for xx in xrange(x-l, x+l+1):
        for yy in xrange(y-l, y+l+1):
            yield (xx, yy)
list(lookup(50, 50, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line, and using the list is not a problem if L is not too large - note that x is the middle x coordinate, y is the middle y, L is half of the length of the box, and grid is your array of tuples:

```
myBox = grid[x - L:x + L][y - L:x + L]
```

If instead you want L to be the full length of the box, you can set x and y to be the lower boundaries and you get

```
myBox = grid[x:x + L][y:y + L]
```